# What aspects of Vault Hunters scale with Overpower Levels?

Tags: borderlands-2

I haven't reached UVHM with any character, let alone Overpower Levels, but I'm curious to know what aspects of a Vault Hunter scale with OP levels.

I know that gear and enemies will scale accordingly, but it seems that certain Action Skills scale to OP levels—for example, I've seen screenshots showing Zer0 Decepti0n decoys and Deathtrap appearing as level 80 when invoked with OP8 characters. (Players have also reported that Axton's Sabre Turret scales to level 80.) However, what other aspects of Vault Hunters scale in a similar fashion?

For example, Krieg has a hidden damage bonus when attacking with his buzz axe which depends on his level ([at 1.6% per level minus 20%](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=4141450&postcount=70)). Is this damage bonus calculated as if the Psycho were 80th level if he's at OP8? (If the melee damage is calculated using level 80, the damage bonus would be 108%, exceeding that of the unique Law pistol. If not, the bonus is 95.2%.)

What else is calculated as if an OP8 character were level 80?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. When playing at the OP levels, you're setting the levels of the enemy and the loot that can drop. Nothing about your character increases past level 72, the max. Not health, not melee damage. Even a COM with a percentage-based increase to something like fire rate is not going to be a huge increase from OP-0 (level 72) to OP-8. You can carry OP-level weapons and other gear, and their stats will scale, but none of yours will past 72.

(And ammo from the vendors gets pretty expensive at OP-8)

Edit: This is not quite correct. See below comment that Maya Phaselock damage does scale past 72. The difference is negligible considering the damage of OP weapons and the significant damage reduction that enemies have at OP-8, but "nothing" is not correct.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this the wrong information? If not, it seems like a good answer to me.

Comment: What you said was that Zero's hologram and Deathtrap were labeled as level 80. That doesn't mean they are. Could be they use the same labeling convention as enemies. If my answer is incorrect, please show why. Does Sal Gunzerk longer in the OP levels? No. Does Maya's Phaselock do more damage? No. Does Zero's Deception damage bonus increase? No.

Comment: Certain Action Skills (and possibly other skills) do scale by level, but as far as I know, Gunzerking duration and Decepti0n damage *bonus percentage* are non-scaling (but the *overall* damage inflicted may as a consequence of OP equipment). Also, Phaselock by itself does not deal damage.

Comment: Well, you're right, and a little wrong. Phaselock does do damage…on enemies that can't be phaselocked (Buzzards, Threshers, etc). The test dummy can't be phaselocked either, so I did a test: Level 72 Maya PL does 1,326K damage. And an OP-8 does 1,586K. Only one skill point spent - in Phaselock. So you are correct that some skills do scale into the OP-levels.

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed the fact that using Phaselock on enemies which cannot be Phaselocked inflicts damage on the target. It's been a while since I've touched my Siren...

Comment: Took me a while to figure it out, but the numbers make perfect sense. At level 80, base damage is increased by a factor of 1.13^8 = 2.6584× relative to level 72. With 55% damage reduction (45% damage applied) on a level 80 target, effective damage inflicted is 1.1693x of normal. This matches up with your Phaselock damage numbers within the limits of precision: 1586/1326 = 1.1961.